# image_tag('#') throw error The asset "#" is not present in the asset pipeline

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

### Steps to reproduce

- Use `#` for `image_tag`

```
image_tag '#', {}
```

### Expected behavior

Should it combine something like this `<img src="#"/>`

### Actual behavior

Raise exception:

```
Sprockets::Rails::Helper::AssetNotFound
The asset "#" is not present in the asset pipeline.
```

#### System configuration

Rails version: 6.0.3

Ruby version: 2.6.6

Comment: I wonder why you want to add an `img` tag to your HTML but do not want to link a valid image? What is the use-case? Especially because browsers usually show a special icon when image links are not working with would break the layout.

Comment: Our main purpose here is to lazy load the picture.

Comment: Why don't you just use the `loading=lazy` option in that case?

Comment: if I'm not wrong, Lazyloading is only available for Chrome 76 onwards.
https://blog.saeloun.com/2021/03/01/rails-6.1-adds-config-for-lazy-image-loading.html

Comment: Looks to me like the most important browser support it by now: https://caniuse.com/loading-lazy-attr

Comment: Oh, I see. 
For most of the browsers, Safaris IOS still does not support it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Found problems:
it seems image_tag became more strict in rails-6 due to asset pipeline upgrade.
For an asset that doesn't exist in pipeline, we can add the option skip_pipeline to avoid exceptions.

```
image_tag '#', skip_pipeline: true
```